# Adding vertices

Tags: vertices, vertex-groups

Is there a way to add vertices to an object in edit mode? Say I want to add some more vertices to a row of vertices of a torus, but do not want to subdivide the whole thing

Comment: select what you want to subdivide and subdivide it?

Answer (score 3):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. you will get the same result as adding a Loop Cut - except it adds a vertice(s) to the string instead of edges.  Then just scroll to decide how many.

This will only allow you to add vertices between two previously added vertices, however.  So, you may want to consider @lemon's suggestion, of selecting the area of vertices where you want to add more and subdividing that area.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you have lets say an edge which has only 2 vertices but you want 3 on 1 edge which means simply that you want to make it into 2 edges , (What i decipher from your question) , then you can select your 2 vertices and right click>Subdivide the vertices

Answer (score 1):

@SHkha's answer is what I would recommend, you positively know where your new vertex is.

However, if, for example, you have a long edge, whose center is inconveniently out of view, you have the option of selecting a vertex you want to duplicate, hovering over the edge you would like the copy to be in, and hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

You can either follow this directly with a transform, (e.g <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>.5</kbd>), or right-click to drop the copy in place, still selected, right on top of  the original.

You can then follow up with your transform, or, say, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to slide it down the edge.